# C# how to return multiple query in foreach

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, linq, c#-4.0

Because currently im like unable to retrieve the issue that

```
        public IQueryable<Issue> commodityMatch_GetData(){

        string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        Context db = new Context();
        IQueryable<Issue> query = db.Issues;
        //currently is filter by commodity and product line
        //looking on how to only filter by commodity

        var x = from r in db.Records
                where r.Username1 == userName
                select r.CommodityID;



        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Im fucking here");
        foreach(int s in x)
        {

            //s got 17 and 18
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
            query = query.Where(p => p.CommodityID == s);
            //how to run mutiple time and return multiple times?
            //return mean end

        }


        return query;
        }
```

For example in var x i have 2 int which is 17 and 18 but in above code i unable to retrieve the issue where the commodity = 17 and 18.

```
        foreach(int s in x)
        {

            //s got 17 and 18
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
            query = query.Where(p => p.CommodityID == s);
            return query;

        }
```

if return query here it only show me issue with commodity 17 and then it didnt show for issue with commodity 18.

Comment: can you update question to show full function please

Comment: I updated the question with full function sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying joining the issues to the records for a single LINQ query:

```
var x = from r in db.Records
        join i in db.Issues
        on r.CommodityID == iCommodityID
        where r.Username1 == userName
        select i;

return x;
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistant. It works fine for the problem that i encounter.  By the way may i know what is the difference between this solution and the way i trying to solve?

Comment: @SadLife - in your original solution, you are looping through your db.Issues but return (exit) after the first one. In your second solution, you are replacing the `query` variable in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thank you, but for the confirmation is that join table are the only way to solve the issue that i face? wish to know more. Thank you.